# Ant design UI library for react, row of type flex as props not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd, ant-design-pro

Using ant design react UI library, I'm trying to create row with three columns of type flex, but still column are not taking flex property.
find the below code:

```js
<Content className="site-layout-background">
    <Row gutter={16} className="homepage-row" type="flex" align="middle">
        <Col className="gutter-row" span={6}>
            <div style={style}>col-6</div>
        </Col>
        
        <Col className="gutter-row" span={6}>
            <div style={style}>col-6</div>
        </Col>

        <Col className="gutter-row" span={6}>
            <div style={style}>col-6</div>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Content>
```

Here is my additional css added,

```css
.ant-row .homepage-row{
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: ant design uses 24 columns. Try to change span={6} to span={8}

Comment: It did worked, but when i try to add one more column after 3rd, it should come to next row right, but it is appending below middle column,